# Java Radio button clear/deselect

Tags: java, swing, awt

I am trying to deselect JRadio button while clear button is pressed. I have tried googling and gone thru lots of forum the only fix i could find is create an invisible button and while clear button is pressed select invisible one. Is there any other method i can use? My code is as follows

```
public class deselectRadioBtn extends JFrame {
    private JRadioButton[] buttons; // array for JRadio buttons

    public deselectRadioBtn() {
        super("Deselect Radio");
        for (int nbrOfButtons = 0; nbrOfButtons < options.length; nbrOfButtons++) {

            //create new JRadioButtons and labels and add ( ) around label
            buttons[nbrOfButtons] = new JRadioButton(( nbrOfButtons +    radioLabel[nbrOfButtons] ));

        //add buttons to eastPanel
        rightPanel.add(options[nbrOfButtons]);
    }//end  for (JRadio)



    //Create a ButtonGroup object, add buttons to the group
    ButtonGroup optionSelect = new ButtonGroup();
    optionSelect.add(buttons[0]);
    optionSelect.add(buttons[1]);
    optionSelect.add(buttons[2]);
    optionSelect.add(buttons[3]);
}
```

This is just a piece of code and i havent include full code.

Comment: If I understood your question correctly you want all radio buttons become deselected, are you?

In this case you have to call:
   optionSelect.clearSelection();
inside your "clear" button action listener.

Comment: yes and use clearSelection(); thanks guys for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `ButtonGroup.clearSelection()`.

Comment: Yes but my radio button is in constructor and active listener is in different class

Comment: What prevents you making `ButtonGroup optionSelect` a field in the class, and making your action listener call a method that calls `optionSelect.clearSelection()`?